# How do I get my rails assets to be served by cloudflare instead of my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudflare

I'm running a rails app on heroku and recently switched to cloudflare for CDN for asset serving. My understanding was that once I use cloudflare, my assets (ie js,css,images) would be served from cloudflare and not from my own server but in my heroku logs I still see the requests for assets. Do I need to configure something in my rails app like setting the asset_host or something? Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure this out for CloudFlare?

Answer (score 4):

It might be helpful to clarify [what CloudFlare caches by default](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) as well (just to make sure you know that not every file extension is automatically cached).

Note: Caching also depends on how many requests we get for the resources before it gets cached (minimum of three).